# Reset transform: rotate() without invoking -webkit-transition: style

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, rotation

I am drawing a wheel on a canvas, rotating it and then wanting to reset the rotation to 0. however due to the css property: `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 15s ease;` when resetting the rotation, it is rotation from `r -> 0` and taking 15 seconds. Is there a way to reset the rotation without invoking the `transform 15s ease`?

I am redrawing data on the canvas after the rotation transform has finished thus needing an instant reset.

Many thanks

```
var r=-(3600 + random);
$("#wheel").css("transform","rotate("+r+"deg)");
$("#wheel").css("-moz-transform","rotate("+r+"deg)");
$("#wheel").css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+r+"deg)");
$("#wheel").css("-o-transform","rotate("+r+"deg)");

$("#wheel").one('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
    $("#wheel").css("transform","none");
    $("#wheel").css("-moz-transform","none");
    $("#wheel").css("-webkit-transform","none");
    $("#wheel").css("-o-transform","none");
});
```

Comment: Not at the moment...No.

Comment: @Paulie_D is there a way to override the current `-webkit-transition:` value and setting it to 1 second during the reset? Then letting it be 15 seconds again afterwards

Comment: Instead of adding the transition to the element, create a class with it and toggle the class on the element when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution for this. By changing the css class to a 'default rotation' class briefly before changing the class to your animated rotation class you can control the animation timing on each separate class in order to have the wheel snap back to the starting position before rotating to your new position.

css:

```
.spin0 {
    transform: rotate(0deg);    
}

.spin750 {
    transform: rotate(750deg) !important;
    transition-duration: 2.5s !important;
}
```

js (on click):

```
element.className = "spin0";

setTimeout(function(){
    element.className = "spin750";
}, 10);
```