# Resetting transform: rotate() by removing and appending canvas not showing data after appending and redrawing chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, chart.js

I am trying to overcome the problem found in my previous question. Since it doesn't seem to be 100% possible I am attempting to destroy the canvas element and re-append it thus clearing all the rotation on the canvas element.

This almost works however the last step, when redrawing the chart from chart.js, nothing appears.

Putting some console.log inside the `onComplete` for the chart.js shows data in the console but nothing appears.

Current [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0y5hr8w/2/) with onComplete data not appearing.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovyr7mt0/) with rotation problem that I am trying to fix.

**Previous question:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027199/reset-transform-rotate-without-invoking-webkit-transition-style)

I am drawing a wheel on a canvas, rotating it and then wanting to reset the rotation to 0. however due to the css property: `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 15s ease;` when resetting the rotation, it is rotation from `r -> 0` and taking 15 seconds. Is there a way to reset the rotation without invoking the `transform 15s ease`?

I am redrawing data on the canvas after the rotation transform has finished thus needing an instant reset.

Many thanks

```
var r=-(3600 + random);
$("#wheel").css("transform","rotate("+r+"deg)");
$("#wheel").css("-moz-transform","rotate("+r+"deg)");
$("#wheel").css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+r+"deg)");
$("#wheel").css("-o-transform","rotate("+r+"deg)");

$("#wheel").one('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
    $("#wheel").css("transform","none");
    $("#wheel").css("-moz-transform","none");
    $("#wheel").css("-webkit-transform","none");
    $("#wheel").css("-o-transform","none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of changes, your code should work

1. Looks like there is some problem with the Chart.js version you are using. I changed it to the latest version (2.1 @ https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.min.js)
2. Before you do `$('#wheel').remove();` you need to do `myChart.destroy();` to remove that particular chart from Chart.js's internal list of objects (which it uses to resize existing charts when the window resizes)
3. The following bit in your code clears off the complete data.

> ```
>     ...
>     for(i=chartData.datasets[0].data.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
>       chartData.datasets[0].data.splice(i,1);
>       chartData.datasets[0].backgroundColor.splice(i,1);
>     }
>     ...
> ```

Since you then user `chartData` to initialize your chart, you are effectively trying to draw a blank chart. I assume this was some sort of copy-paste error. I've changed it in the updated fiddle to just remove the last sector alone, like so.

```
var i=chartData.datasets[0].data.length-1;
chartData.datasets[0].data.splice(i,1);
chartData.datasets[0].backgroundColor.splice(i,1);
```

If you want all the sectors again for the next run, just remove that block.

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wzbxuo5n/